# What happens if choose only my Ip in the security group inbound rule for ssh & http in AWS EC2 instance

Tags: aws, amazon-ec2

I am a student and trying to get a grasp on how does the inbound rule in the security group for EC2 instance in AWS work.

I tried setting up couple of rules SSH & HTTP for only My IP but when I do that I cannot see the `index.html` page stored in `/var/www/html/` in my Amazon linux 2 AMI.

If I choose HTTP for anywhere then I can see my `index.html` page.
I thought If I put only My IP in HTTP & SSH I will be the only one who will be able to see the `index.html` page and modify via terminal.

Can anyone help me understand what is the way to do that?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is about AWS and not a Unix or Linux problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What IP did you put in the SG? If it starts with `10.x.x.x` or `172.16.x.x` to `172.31.x.x` or `192.168.x.x` then you’ve put in your *private IP* that’s only valid in your local network.

You have to find out your **public IP** using a service like [ifconfig.co](https://ifconfig.co) and put that in the SG.

Hope that helps :)